# Is there a way to tag or identify specific orders?

Tags: shopify

Using the webhook api to retrieve orders, I'm wondering if there's some way that the orders can be tagged in some form so I can attribute them to certain objects in a shopify app. The scenario is a client wishes to be able to attribute certain orders to different charities. Is there a way they can identify the orders as such?

One thing I can think of is the visitor chooses a "product" which simply dictates which charity they wish the order sale to be donated to, and I look for that product in the webhook. But i wonder if there's another way.

Comment: how about a drop down in the checkout page. do not know how to customize the checkout page. just suggesting it could be there

Comment: I like the idea, I'm just not sure how that would work on the data side. Something has to be attached to the order data itself so I can identify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [cart.note](http://wiki.shopify.com/Cart_variables#cart.note) or [cart.attributes](http://wiki.shopify.com/Cart_variables#cart.attributes). They allow you to store custom properties with your order.

If you need a per product attribute, you can use [Line Item Properties](http://wiki.shopify.com/Line_Item_Properties).

Comment: Ah excellent. Was thinking of looking at the Cart API more closely to see if it had something like that. I'll have to explore it a bit, but i think that should do the job.